# remove html 5 table row containing data- attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I understand how to get the attribute of an table object `$('#tableid tr').attr('data-id')` that uses HTML5 data- attributes. However when I try to remove the row based on the data-id attribute, it doesn't seem to work.

When I did something like this:

```
var theRowId = $('#tableid tr').attr('data-id');
$('#tableid tr#'+theRowId).remove();
```

it didn't work. Html 5 data-attributes should be handled like any other attribute, correct?

Comment: `data-id` and `id` are totally different. Don't confuse the two. Also, why is there a `<br/>` tag in your script?

Comment: Yes, you can handle data attributes just like normal attributes, however  your first line only gets the value of the first tr's data attribute. the next line assumes that a tr exists that has an `id="thedataattributevalue"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the Index of the tr you want the **data-attribute** from

`$('#tableid tr:eq(0)');`  // First row in table

`$('#tableid tr:eq(1)');`  // Second row in table

Because there might be multiple rows in the table

```
var theRowId = $('#tableid tr:eq(1)').attr('data-id'); // Get the Second Row id
$('#tableid tr#'+theRowId).remove();  // Remove the row with id
```

OR if you **know the ID of the Row**.. simply  do this

```
$('#tableid tr[data-id="'+theRowId+'"]').remove();
```

Comment: the table is generated dynamically so I cant pass the index as operationally it should handle whatever row...

Comment: What is the row that you want to delete

Comment: this worked: var theRowId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('#tableThing tr[data-id="' + theRowId + '"]').remove();

Answer (score 6):

You need to change how you're selecting for the data-id attribute.
Try selecting for the row like this:

```
$('#tableid tr[data-id="'+theRowId+'"]').remove();
```

This will select for the tr with the data-id attribute that matches.

Answer (score 2):

data-id is not like id

You need to do this:

```
  $('#tableid tr[data-id='+ theRowId +']').remove()
```